# How can I compare the previous value with the current value

Tags: javascript

I've created a dice roll script but the problem is when it draws the same number it looks as though it hasn't changed number.

I thought of two solutions to the problem, one was to add some sort of check that if the current value is equal to the previous value then it will display the words "again".

I also wanted to animate the characters but because its being inserted by JS it seems to ignore the animation put on the container.

```css
#rollCount {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Dice Roll</h1>
<h2>Your fate awaits...</h2>
<div id="rollCount"></div>
<button class="" onclick="diceRoll()">Dice Roll</button>

<script>
  function diceRoll() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    document.getElementById('rollCount').innerHTML = "<h3>" + number + "</h3>";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The code snippet that you have included gives me different numbers, when I press the button. Didn't you state that the same number would occur again and again?

Comment: No, it's a dice roll its supposed to give out random numbers, but since its only from 1 to 6 the numbers repeat sometimes but it looks like they haven't changed because there's no way to distinguish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user rolls the same number twice in a row and the computer is *supposed* to display **again**...try this...

```
<h1>Dice Roll</h1>
<h2>Your fate awaits...</h2>
<div id="rollCount"></div>
<button onclick="diceRoll()">Dice Roll</button>

<script>
  function diceRoll() {
   var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   var prev = document.getElementById('rollCount').innerText;
   if(number == parseInt(prev))
     document.getElementById('rollCount').innerHTML = "<h3 class='fade-in' >again</h3>";
   else
     document.getElementById('rollCount').innerHTML = "<h3 class='fade-in' >" + number + "</h3>";
  }
</script>
```

Now, to add a **fade-in** on the element...

```
@keyframes fadeAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:.5; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:.5; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:.5; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:.5; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
.fade-in {
   -webkit-animation: fadeAnimation 1s;
   -moz-animation: fadeAnimation 1s;
   -o-animation: fadeAnimation 1s;
    animation: fadeAnimation 1s;
}
```

Jsfiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/bzjg5yo6/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

create a class and add/remove it every time the user clicks the button. Also set the opacity of #rollCount to 1 so that when you remove the class it will still show.

```
 <style>
        #rollCount {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        #rollCount.fade-in {
            animation-name: fade-in;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-duration: 2s;
        }

        @keyframes fade-in {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    </style>
<h1>Dice Roll</h1>
    <h2>Your fate awaits...</h2>
    <div id="rollCount"></div>
    <button class="" onclick="diceRoll()">Dice Roll</button>

<script>
        function diceRoll() {
            var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            document.getElementById('rollCount').className +=' fade-in';
            document.getElementById('rollCount').innerHTML = "<h3>" + number + "</h3>";
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('rollCount').classList.remove('fade-in');
            }, 1000)

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yeah that works perfect, but is there anyway to link it to the button click instead of 1s for the timeout?